# Cambiar imagen ImageButton sin definir

Tags: java, android

Tengo varios ImageButton, y quiero que con un mismo proceso OnClick pueda cambiar la imagen únicamente del ImageButton que haya sido pulsado, o lo que sería lo mismo, leer la id del botón pulsado.

Se que el método es setImageResource()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado lo que buscaba, lo pongo por si alguien más tiene la misma duda:

```
 public void click(View view) {
    ImageButton imgbt = findViewById(view.getId());

    if (lastCross == true) {
        imgbt.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
        lastCross = flase
    }
    else {
        imgbt.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
        lastCross = true
    }
}
```